# Как добавить условие по дате в запрос?

Tags: sql

У меня есть запрос который работает и выводит данные. Мне нужно еще это все сортировать по дате.

```
SELECT dd.caption, COUNT(t.occurence) 
  FROM transaction t 
  INNER JOIN dict_departments dd
    ON dd.id = t.terminal_id
GROUP BY dd.caption
```

Я не знаю как добавить имеющиеся условие:

```
WHERE t.occurence BETWEEN (CURRENT_DATE() - INTERVAL 1 MONTH)
```

Comment: Не совсем понятно, нужно сортировать или же фильтровать? Да и про SQL движок ни слова.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Возможно, так:

```
SELECT dd.caption, COUNT(t.occurence) 
  FROM transaction t 
  INNER JOIN dict_departments dd
    ON dd.id = t.terminal_id
WHERE t.occurence > (CURRENT_DATE() - INTERVAL 1 MONTH)
GROUP BY dd.caption
```

Comment: Обратите внимание, что `>` и `BETWEEN` это разные условия.

Answer (score 1):

Ответы на ваши вопросы есть в документации к SQL движку. Например, если у вас MYSQL:

1. Условие WHERE вставляете перед GROUP (и почитайте [синтаксис BETWEEN](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/comparison-operators.html#operator_between))
2. Сортировку указываем через [ORDER BY](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/select.html)